# Converting String to Hex (from bluetooth inputStream)

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth

Im reading data input from bluetooth as byte which i then pass to String so I can format the text to display on the screen, this all works just fine, part of this received data is in hex (just a decimal number from 1 to 50, so two digits)

So for example I receive the message: `01theCatSatOnTheMat` (converted to string)

because the number is hex I get: `-theCatSatOnTheMat` (converted to string)

according to the ascii table 0-31 are unprintable characters so how can i convert them back to Hex so i can display 01theCatSatOnTheMat on the screen?

is it that i need to take the number part and convert from byte to hex first then to decimal to display while the rest will be put straight from byte to string?

and if so I'm not sure how to say which bytes to pick from the input stream to convert as usually i just go something like:

```
String receivedText = new String(buffer); //where buffer is my received bytes
 TextView.setText(receivedText); //display it in this textView
```

however I do a bit of editing before its put to the screen but that isn't relevant here.

cheers.

Comment: If you receive byte data that isn't all encoded characters you should display this as a "hexadecimal dump", showing two hexadecimal characters for each byte, 16 bytes per line, and, in the right margin, a string containing the characters (if printable) and '.' for control characters.

Comment: is it possible to receive hex 0-31(control characters) and display as decimal? the numbers being sent will always be in the range 1 - 50

Comment: If you have buffer as a byte[], simply print its integer value: `Integer.toString(buffer[i])`. If its value is `buffer[i]>=' ' && buffer[i]<='~'`, you can print it as a character: `print( (char)buffer[i] )`.